# What is the best way to extract text from strings with html tags in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract text from the string below

```js
<br /><b>The Pioneer Woman Flea Market Stoneware Coasters, Set of 4:</b><ul><li>4" coasters</li><li>Decorative and functional</li><li>Pioneer Woman coasters have willow floral designs</li><li>Stoneware</li><li>Hand wash only</li><li>Use to protect tabletops and other surfaces</li><li>Set of 4 coasters make a wonderful gift</li></ul>
```

I tried using this xml

```js
def remove_htmltags(text):
    return ''.join(ET.fromstring(text).itertext())
```

but I keep getting the error

> > xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 1, column 6

what is the best way to extract text from the string with html tags?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need text not from specific tag, Use `beautifulSoup`

```
In [26]: html = """<br /><b>The Pioneer Woman Flea Market Stoneware Coasters, Set of 4:</b><ul><li>4" coasters</li><li
    ...: >Decorative and functional</li><li>Pioneer Woman coasters have willow floral designs</li><li>Stoneware</li><l
    ...: i>Hand wash only</li><li>Use to protect tabletops and other surfaces</li><li>Set of 4 coasters make a wonderf
    ...: ul gift</li></ul>
    ...: """

In [27]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [28]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [29]: soup.text
Out[29]: 'The Pioneer Woman Flea Market Stoneware Coasters, Set of 4:4" coastersDecorative and functionalPioneer Woman coasters have willow floral designsStonewareHand wash onlyUse to protect tabletops and other surfacesSet of 4 coasters make a wonderful gift\n'
```

OR ONLY FROM `<li>` tags

```
In [30]: [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("li")]
Out[30]:
['4" coasters',
 'Decorative and functional',
 'Pioneer Woman coasters have willow floral designs',
 'Stoneware',
 'Hand wash only',
 'Use to protect tabletops and other surfaces',
 'Set of 4 coasters make a wonderful gift']
```